# Want to use FirstName from UserInfo table instead of UserName from ASPNetUsers table in ASP.NET Identity LoggedIn info in Web form Application

Tags: asp.net

I have used ASP.NET Identity for Login and the table by default used in this is **AspNetUsers**. I have created separate **UserInfo** table with **FirstName**, **LastName** and **UserId** columns where UserId is the unique Identifier and referenced to **AspNetUsers** **Id** column table. Now, I want to display **FirstName** from **UserInfo** table instead of **UserName** from **AspNetUsers**.

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hi,  <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName() %></a></li>
```

I have researched it on Stackoverflow but could not find the solution of how to do in Web form. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in Asp.net Identity you need to load and keep the `User.FirstName` in the Session object at the time of login. And then use it when ever you need.

```
//after verifying the credential with SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync function
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
Session["UserFirstName"] = user.FirstName;
```

Now

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hi,  <%: Session["UserFirstName"] %></a></li>
```

You can also create two extension methods `SetUserFirstName` and `GetUserFirstName` for `Page` or `UserControl` or `Session` types and instead of calling `Session["UserFirstName"]` directly use these methods and in `GetUserFirstName` first check if `Session["UserFirstName"]` is null then redirect the page to login.aspx or whatever.

Comment: Hi @Cruiser KID, I am new to web form so could not understand how to implement this code into my application. My code for login.ascx is: 
  var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
 var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text) 
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                break;    }